Estimating the gradient of the log-density of a Markov process
Let $(X_t)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$ be an $\mathbb R^d$-valued time-homogeneous Markov process with respect to a probability measure $\operatorname P_x$ so that $\operatorname P_x[X_0=x]=1$. Assume $$\operatorname P_x[X_t\in B]=\int_Bp_t(x,y)\:{\rm d}y\;\;\;\text{for all }(x,B)\in\mathbb R^d\times\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)\tag1$$ for some Borel measurable $p_t:\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d\to[0,\infty)$. Fix a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^d$ and note that $$\operatorname P_\mu[X_t\in B]:=\int\mu({\rm d}x)\operatorname P_x\left[X_t\in B\right]=\int_B\underbrace{\int p_t(x,y)\:\mu({\rm d}x)}_{=:\:p_t}\:{\rm d}y\tag2$$ for all $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ and $t\in\overline[0,T]$.
Question: What I actually want to obtain is an estimate $(\tilde s_t)_{t\in\overline I}$ of $$s_t(y):=\nabla\ln p_t(y)\;\;\;\text{for }(t,y)\in[0,T]\times\mathbb R^d$$ by minimizing $$L(\tilde s):=\int_0^T\operatorname E_\mu\left[\left\|(\tilde s_t-s_t)(X_t)\right\|^2\right]\:{\rm d}t.\tag3$$ Now, say I minimize $$\hat L(\tilde s):=\int_0^T\int\mu({\rm d}x)\operatorname E_x\left[\left\|\tilde s_t(X_t)-s_t(x,X_t)\right\|^2\right]\:{\rm d}t\tag4$$ instead, where $$s_t(x,y):=\nabla_y\ln p_t(x,y)\;\;\;\text{for }(t,x,y)\in[0,T]\times\mathbb R^d\times\mathbb R^d.$$ What is the relation between the obtained estimates obtained by minimizing $(3)$ and $(4)$, respectively? Are they equal? If not, can we express one in terms of the other?
If I'm not mistaken, we should have $$s_t(y)=\int\mu({\rm d}x)\frac{p_t(x,y)}{p_t(y)}s_t(x,y)\tag5,$$ but I'm not able to continue from this.

In the interest of exposition, I will assume that $\mu$ is a density, but it should not make too much of a difference. I will also assume enough regularity to pass derivatives under the integral sign freely. Let $\rho_t(x,y)$ be the joint density of $(X_0,X_t)$ (i.e., $\rho_t(x,y)=\mu(x)p_t(y,x))$.
We have
\begin{align} s_t(y) &= \frac{\nabla_y p_t(y)}{p_t(y)}= \int \frac{\nabla_y p_t(y, x)}{p_t(y)}\mu(x)\,dx \\
&= \int \frac{\nabla_y p_t(y, x)}{p_t(y,x)} \cdot \frac{p_t(x,y)}{p_t(y)}\mu(x)\,dx\\
&= \int s_t(x,y) \frac{\rho_t(x,y)}{p_t(y)}\,dx=\mathbb{E}[s_t(X_0,X_t) \mid X_t=y].
\end{align}
Now, your second minimization problem is
\begin{align*}\min \hat L(f)&=\int_0^T\int\mu({\rm d}x)\operatorname E_x\left[\left\|f_t(X_t)-s_t(x,X_t)\right\|^2\right]\:{\rm d}t\tag4\\
&= \min \int_0^T \iint |f_t(y)-s_t(x,y)|^2 p_t(y,x)\,dy\,\mu(x)\,dx\,dt\\
&= \min \int_0^T \iint |f_t(y)-s_t(x,y)|^2 \rho_t(x,y)\,dx\,dy\,dt
\\&= \min \int_0^T \mathbb{E}[|f_t(X_t)-s_t(X_0,X_t)|^2]\,dt\end{align*}
The time variable is irrelevant (we can just pick the optimal f_t for each t). To solve the inner minimization problem, we can use the tower property
$$\mathbb{E}[|f_t(X_t)-s_t(X_0,X_t)|^2] = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[\left|f_t(X_t)-s_t(X_0,X_t)\right|^2\mid X_t\right]\right]$$
The inner minimization problem is solved by $f_t^*(X_t)=\mathbb{E}[s_t(X_0,X_t)\mid X_t]$, which thus solves the whole problem. By the above, $f^*_t(y)=s_t(y)$.
